# inflate android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView inflateException

Tags: android, android-support-library

I started migrating my app to material design so I changed one of my ImageViews to android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView  and the app crashes the fact is that it can't inflate it but if I use the same as CircleImageView from android v21 on a lollipop device works perfectly with the same attributtes.

so to test it alone I've created a new project with only this View under the layout and still crashes.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_lists_user_profile_picture"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_new" />
```

also I found people with the same problem with a [google ticket](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=85049), but it was marked as spam :(

Does any one knows which are the requirements of CircleImageView support v4 library

Comment: I was able to take the source code from the link @Kenneth provided and compiled myself a CircleImageView by completing their code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/v4/widget/CircleImageView.java

Says CircleImageView is a private class? Means you can't use it.

Comment: thanks for answering,  but the fact is  clearly the objective of the class was to bring shadows to older devices. and also if its private must be kept private so the editor doesn't suggest you using it instead of CircleImageView for pre lollipop devices.  hope we will have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android Studio, you can just Cmd+B (using a Mac) into the class, copy and paste into a new class file and use it straight away. By right there shouldn't be any other custom attributes being used.

Answer (score 0):

it's package local, you can create a new class in the same namespace `android.support.v4.widget` that inherits CircleImageView, perhaps it may not work in future releases of the support library

```
package android.support.v4.widget;

public class MyCircleImageView extends CircleImageView {
     // constructors
}
```