# Why don't set CircleImageView of android support v4 library public?

Tags: android, imageview

I have noticed `android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView` for long. Every time I want to use an `ImageView` in a round shape, `CircleImageView` would appear in my mind. I have tried to use it for many times, but every time, I failed. Because the access permission of `android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView` is ***default*** which means only classes in the same package with `CircleImageView`, namely, `android.support.v4.widget`, are able to access it.

I can't understand now that round `ImageView` is used in common, why don't set `CircleImageView` to public so that developers don't have to override an `ImageView` into a Round ImageView? Isn't it that Google Android team force us to **reinvent wheels**?

Or, don't I know this `CircleImageView` well?

Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (not the downvoter) but the answer is: who knows? Have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616578/inflate-android-support-v4-widget-circleimageview-inflateexception + http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/v4/widget/CircleImageView.java + http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=85049. No one seems to have an answer but there are quite a few third party open source libs you can import that give you the same behavior (and more).

Comment: @ChrisBanes is working at Android. But I don't know how to @ him

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know how to @ people who aren't in the conversation I'm afraid :(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to copy and paste source codes of `android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView` to make it public just like this:

```
package me.danielpan.youtubelike.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RadialGradient;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Private class created to work around issues with AnimationListeners being
 * called before the animation is actually complete and support shadows on older
 * platforms.
 *
 * @hide
 */
public class CircleImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final int KEY_SHADOW_COLOR = 0x1E000000;
    private static final int FILL_SHADOW_COLOR = 0x3D000000;
    // PX
    private static final float X_OFFSET = 0f;
    private static final float Y_OFFSET = 1.75f;
    private static final float SHADOW_RADIUS = 3.5f;
    private static final int SHADOW_ELEVATION = 4;

    private Animation.AnimationListener mListener;
    private int mShadowRadius;

    public CircleImageView(Context context, int color, final float radius) {
        super(context);
        final float density = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        final int diameter = (int) (radius * density * 2);
        final int shadowYOffset = (int) (density * Y_OFFSET);
        final int shadowXOffset = (int) (density * X_OFFSET);

        mShadowRadius = (int) (density * SHADOW_RADIUS);

        ShapeDrawable circle;
        if (elevationSupported()) {
            circle = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
            ViewCompat.setElevation(this, SHADOW_ELEVATION * density);
        } else {
            OvalShape oval = new OvalShadow(mShadowRadius, diameter);
            circle = new ShapeDrawable(oval);
            ViewCompat.setLayerType(this, ViewCompat.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, circle.getPaint());
            circle.getPaint().setShadowLayer(mShadowRadius, shadowXOffset, shadowYOffset,
                    KEY_SHADOW_COLOR);
            final int padding = mShadowRadius;
            // set padding so the inner image sits correctly within the shadow.
            setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        }
        circle.getPaint().setColor(color);
        setBackgroundDrawable(circle);
    }

    private boolean elevationSupported() {
        return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (!elevationSupported()) {
            setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth() + mShadowRadius*2, getMeasuredHeight()
                    + mShadowRadius*2);
        }
    }

    public void setAnimationListener(Animation.AnimationListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart() {
        super.onAnimationStart();
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onAnimationStart(getAnimation());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd() {
        super.onAnimationEnd();
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onAnimationEnd(getAnimation());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the background color of the circle image view.
     *
     * @param colorRes Id of a color resource.
     */
    public void setBackgroundColorRes(int colorRes) {
        setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(colorRes));
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        if (getBackground() instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
            ((ShapeDrawable) getBackground()).getPaint().setColor(color);
        }
    }

    private class OvalShadow extends OvalShape {
        private RadialGradient mRadialGradient;
        private Paint mShadowPaint;
        private int mCircleDiameter;

        public OvalShadow(int shadowRadius, int circleDiameter) {
            super();
            mShadowPaint = new Paint();
            mShadowRadius = shadowRadius;
            mCircleDiameter = circleDiameter;
            mRadialGradient = new RadialGradient(mCircleDiameter / 2, mCircleDiameter / 2,
                    mShadowRadius, new int[] {
                    FILL_SHADOW_COLOR, Color.TRANSPARENT
            }, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            mShadowPaint.setShader(mRadialGradient);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
            final int viewWidth = CircleImageView.this.getWidth();
            final int viewHeight = CircleImageView.this.getHeight();
            canvas.drawCircle(viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2, (mCircleDiameter / 2 + mShadowRadius),
                    mShadowPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2, (mCircleDiameter / 2), paint);
        }
    }
}
```

It looks well, right? It has no customized attributes and seems able to be used as a normal `ImageView`.

But if you have tried it, you will find out that `NoSuchMethodException` is thrown. This exception implies that necessary constructors are not overridden. So that you can't even instantiate it as a normal `View`.

After reading these source codes, I realize that `CircleImageView` only adds shadow behind `ImageView`, whose result is not a `RoundCornerImageView` or `RoundImageView`. So if I want a `RoundImageView`, I have to forget this class and implement this effect by overriding an `ImageView`.

At last, there is the file comment,  which points out the use of `android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView`:

> Private class created to work around issues with AnimationListeners
>   being  called before the animation is actually complete and support
>   shadows on older platforms.

And I hope no one will ask such a stupid question again and let it end here, ^_^, Haha~

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation this class is private class used for work around and we cannot instantiate it. May be that class will be removed sooner I suspect.

There are ways to create the circular background for a view.

file : drawable/contact_badge_round.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">

    <size android:width="32dp" android:height="32dp"/>

    <gradient android:centerColor="#123456" <!--Put your custom color for bg -->
              android:startColor="#123456"
              android:endColor="#123456"
        />

</shape>
```

then in your layout create a Button and set the background as contact_badge_round

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/roundContact"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawalbe/your_image"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/background_new_entity_symbol"
       />
```

Comment: It's a way to implement shadow effect.

Comment: This won't add the shadow, it will create a circular view!

Comment: It will add shadow on API21+ but you need to add `android:outlineProvider="background"`.